# Is an exterior algebra a skew group ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can an exterior algebra 
$$
k\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n} \rangle/(x_{1}x_{2}-x_{2}x_{1},\dots,x_{1}^{2},\dots)
$$
can be seen as a skew group algebra?

A skew group ring is defined for example in the introduction of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0303229v1.pdf). I read this fact(?) somewhere but I cannot find a group action $G \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(k)$ that cooks up the exterior algebra.

Comment: Should it not be $x_ix_j+x_jx_i$?

Comment: I would be interested in knowing what $G$ you had in mind.

Comment: I'm guessing there are two usages of "skew" here. Probably the exterior algebra is "skew" in the sense that it's not quite commutative.

Comment: "skew group algebra" tends to mean "cross product of the group and a field" with a nontrivial action.

Comment: @JimConant The standard group ring construction causes coefficients to commute with the group basis elements. The paper referenced by the OP uses skew to mean "has a rule which modifies commuting coefficients with elements of $G$". This is conventional in noncommutative algebra.

Comment: @rschwieb: So "skew" in both cases basically means "noncommutative."

Comment: @JimConant I still don't know what second case you are thinking of, but yes, skew constructions are usually noncommutative.

Comment: @rschwieb: Case 1 is the skew group ring and case 2 is the exterior algebra.

Comment: @JimConant Ah! "Skew" as in skew matrices and skew-symmetry! Natural thing I should have picked up on :) Yeah those two are completely different things in my mind... and they appear to be unrelated terms as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

If there is such a thing as "[Maschke's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem) for skew group rings" (I think one might be proven [here](http://books.google.com/books?ei=4vgkUKmZJ8jZrAGx64DwCw&id=rZPvAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22Skew+group+rings+and+applications+to+modules%22&q=Corollary+0.2)), then the answer would often be "no".

Since the exterior algebra of a finite dimensional vector space is a local ring, there is no way it's going to be semisimple (meaning "semisimple Artinian") unless it's already a field (and of course it's not a field, since it has nilpotent elements).